# Implementing Deep Linking in Swift not working

Tags: swift, syntax-error, declaration, deep-linking, url-link

I am trying to implement deep linking via [this tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/):

When i copy the first code block in, i get errors related to the declaration of

```
var deepLink : RemoteNotificationDeepLink?
```

most of which can be traced back to

> **Use of undeclared type 'RemoteNotificationDeepLink'.**

There are no comments on the tutorial and this is the only good tutorial i have found thats not in Obj-C. Either a solution to this error or another tutorial would be much appreciated

Comment: I think you're not finished to read the tutorial, if you download the final project and you continue reading you'll see the declaration of the class `RemoteNotificationDeepLink`

Comment: you are right. If you copy the rest of the code it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you proceed to copy the remaining code blocks and follow the instructions, the solution is presented

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have not defined `var deepLink : RemoteNotificationDeepLink?` from the tutorial. That is in the second code block. All you need to do is finish the tutorial before you try and run it too see if it works. So you are trying to use it but your application does not have any context of what it is.

Check out this deepLinking explanation from another question 
[Confused with IOS Deep linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666052/confused-with-ios-deep-linking/35424780#35424780)

let me know if you are still having issues.